# Editing TXT file content using a wildcard

Tags: batch-file, variable-substitution

I'm working on a content editor, which will edit the data inside a txt file, changing it to whatever you programmed it to.

This is my original script:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=Stars"
set "replace=Falling Stars"

set "textFile=0Originals\Document.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

This is my attempt:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=Stars"
set "replace=Falling Stars"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "0Originals\*.txt" ^& break ^> "0Originals\*.txt" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"0Originals\*.txt" echo (!line:%search%=%replace%!%%
    endlocal
)
```

I am trying to to make it read any file, but everything I do fails to work.

Any idea on why the `*.txt` fails to work?

Comment: Why not use an outer `for` loop, i.e. ```For %%G In ("0Originals\*.txt") Do For /F "Delims=" %%i In ('Type "%%~G" ^& Break 1^>"%%~G"') Do …```

Comment: I'd prefer however to change the outer loop to only perform the task on files which include the search string, so would probably change the outer loop to a `for /f` with `findstr.exe` and its `/M` option.

Comment: @Compo - Like this - `Do findstr.exe /m "Delims="` I'm sure I'm placing this wrong because when I added this it failed... does the `/m` belong somewhere else

Comment: like this `Do For /F "Delims="` worked perfectly and you what on the way home, I thought about separating this and doing something like this `For %%G In ("0Originals\*.txt")` - all my testing was build everything together - and now I have a fix for another script

Comment: what is the best way to isolate the search for example I have `Stars` and `HotStars` and I only want to find Stars

Comment: No, like this: ```For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /MLIC:"%search%" "0Originals\*.txt" 2^>NUL') Do For /F "Delims=" %%i In ('Type "%%~G" ^& Break 1^>"%%~G"') Do …``` If you wanted just the word `Stars` then perhaps ```%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RMIC:"\<%search%\>" "0Originals\*.txt"```. Honestly, those things are explained in the help information `findstr /?`, and that should be your first port of call, not here.

Comment: Wow...OK yes I am no good with `.exe` methods

Comment: `Any idea on why the *.txt fails to work?` Yes - you can't redirect to a set of files (`*.txt`) but only to a unique file name. That's why previous comments suggested two `for` loops (one to separate `*.txt` to single files, the other to process those files)